# Adjustment brush: How to see which portions of the picture you've altered?

Tags: post-processing, adobe-camera-raw, brushes

When using the Adjustment brush, I remember a hotkey or button somewhere which will render the image dark and show you where you've used the brush. It's helpful, so you know that you have/haven't, accidently, altered portions of the picture you didn't want any adjustment to.

I'm using Camera RAW in Photoshop CC 2015

Answer (score 4):

According to [the Adobe help on camera raw](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/using/make-local-adjustments-camera-raw.html):

> **To toggle visibility of the mask overlay**, use the Show Mask option, **press Y**, or position the pointer over the pin icon.
>
> *To customize the color of the mask overlay, click the color swatch next to the Show Mask option. Then, choose a new color from the Color Picker.*

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it was called Mask Overlay, so I didn't know what to google.

Answer (score 1):

1) Alt + click On the layer mask to see the mask
2) Shift+ click on the layer mask to hide the mask
3) Ctrl + click on the layer mask to select the masked area

Comment: This is for a Mask in Photoshop, the person is asking about Adjustments made within the initial Camera Raw dialog